# Episode of possibly The Outer Limits w/ mind-controlled alien spaceship found in a cave?

Tags: aliens, spaceship, episode-identification, mind-control, the-outer-limits

I remember an episode of what I think to have been The Outer Limits, but I can't seem to be able to identify it. The plot is as follows:

Some children/teens play outside and at one point they find a cave. They enter the cave and find a strange alien-like object which emits a sound/light. They are fascinated by it and start going there repeatedly in the following days. At one point they start to feel sick and they are brought to a doctor. After a CT scan he discovers that they all have been developing some kind of brain tumors, most likely caused by the exposure to the object (radiation?).

One of the teens, after hearing the terrible news, decides to go back to the cave, as he had nothing left to lose and wanted to know the truth about what happened. He gets close to the object and then it opens, revealing what seemed to be the control room of a spaceship, which contained a chair for the pilot. As he sits on the chair, the ship starts up and he gets immobilized by metal straps. Immediately, a metal object from the back of the chair is painfully inserted in the back of his skull, deep inside his brain.

The teen telepathically receives the thought that he can now control the spaceship with his mind. He is amazed by this and eagerly flies the ship away from Earth and into the cosmos using only his thoughts. The final moments of the episode deliver a shock: Because he is only human, worrisome by nature, he starts to think of a self-destruct feature of the ship. A timer to self-destruction gets activated and he cannot stop it because he cannot help thinking that the ship will explode (in the same way of trying NOT to think of a pink elephant... you just did). The ship eventually explodes, leaving the viewer perplexed.

Any ideas of which episode I've just described?
Thank you.

Comment: This is less than helpful, but my https://youtu.be/3_Thc5SrBXg lets you view all episodes of the original Outer Limits rapidly. You *may* be able to recognize your episode by watching this, but it's a long shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching far and wide I've actually found the closest match to my description. It's Stephen King's Tommyknockers movie.
The plot is in no way similar to what i've described (I probably combined elements from many SF series and movies of the time), but the scene with the mind controlled spaceship being destroyed most likely is what I remember.

Comment: I've never seen the Tommyknockers movie, but I have to say the *start* of your description sounds more like the book than the end...